# Shell script to move all files from subfolders to parent folder

Tags: bash, scripts

I've bunch of folders in folder `A`. I want to move files from all those folders to `A`.

Or

I want to cut all files from child folders and paste them in parent folder.

How to do that?

Comment: I haven't really tested this to be foolproof or anything, but have you tried simply entering this command from Folder A in a terminal:  `mv */* .`?

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicate file names?

Comment: `mv */* .` won't move files from subfolders' subfolder.

Comment: @jippie yep, there are no duplicate names

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Go to your `A` directory and run

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;
```

which means "find all files in this directory and its sub-directories and execute mv with target directory . for each file found to move them to current directory.

Comment: it also tries to move files which are already in parent directory.

Comment: virpara: now this your edition forgets all files in .dot directories. Revised it with -mindepth 2 instead to suppress warnings.

Comment: With GNU `find` you can be a little more elegant and not spawn a `mv` process for each file: `find A -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -t A \{\} +`

Comment: David, your version works until you hit maximum command line length limit, which isn't that hard to do given how find prints out the paths, especially in case where you invoke it from directory other than A, like in your example.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why the `\;` is needed at the end?

Comment: thank you so much. This is why i luv linux and the community

Comment: This is very dangerous. if you have files with the same file name in different subfolders, you will overwrite all of these with the last find. Better to use mv with --backup=numbered: `find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv --backup=numbered {} . \;`

Comment: This works, but its kind of slow on a windows machine

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed, although I used `--backup=numbered` as suggested by @pLumo. One more suggestion: after having moved all files into the target directory, only empty folders remain. To quickly get rid of them, I used `find . -empty -type d -delete`.

Answer (score 5):

Well you could create a file and name it "cutme" (to create a file called cutme in the terminal type `nano cutme`. To save it press CTRL+X then press ENTER.) for example and paste the following in it assuming that:

1. You want to do this recursively (In subfolders and subfolders of those subfolders)
2. You want to skip moving the script file
3. You have permissions to move the files in that folder
4. Files may or may not include spaces in their names

`find * -type f -print -not -type d -and -not -regex 'cutme' -exec mv {} .. \;`

Note the name **cutme** inside the line. It should be the same as the script you will run.

After creating the file and pasting the above line, run the following in the same folder as the script:

`chmod +x cutme`. This will give your new file the "Executable" flag so you can execute it like this: `./cutme`.

Comment: Why should I try to move files those are already in parent directory?

Comment: You would run the script from inside the folder. Every file in it, if inside a subfolder or not would move to the folder's parent folder. The parent folder here is the parent in relation to where the script is. Actually by changing the last 2 dots you can tell where to move all files inside a folder where you run the script.